# Bash scripting input request keep looping even no loop

Tags: bash

I'm having headache on figuring out on this problem. Hope you guys can help to figure it out.  Here is the code bash script snippet

```
function nmap {
    echo - e "What is your host? \c"
    read hosts
    mkdir - p $report_path$hosts 2 > /dev/null
    output = "Nmap_Default_Scan_Report"
    nmap - p - -A - sV--version - intensity 5--script = whois - ip $hosts - oX $report_path$output.xml 2 > /dev/null#
    xml2html $hosts $output
    recon
}
```

The problem is, the script keeps looping requesting for "What is your host?". What happen? I didn't setup any loop there.

Full Source Code was here:
https://github.com/exrienz/s1mpl3/blob/master/simple.sh

Comment: This question seems to be off-topic. It seems to be more about bash scripting than about information security.

Comment: Im trying to create security based bash script. .. It wasn't counted?

Answer (score 1):

When you try to call the `nmap` program, you actually call the `nmap` function. The error occurs because by naming your function `nmap` you now have two things with the same name.